# On ubuntu 20.04 LTS can not install postgis

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, 20.04, postgresql

When I try to install postgis with:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-12-postgis-2.5
```

I run into an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-12-postgis-2.5 : Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then when I try to install libgdal20, I run into more dependency issues

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgdal20 : Depends: gdal-data (>= 2.2.3+dfsg-2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libhdf5-100 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libnetcdf13 (>= 4.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libogdi3.2 (>= 3.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can someone guide me through the correct way to install postgis?

#### Update

This is the result of my `sudo apt update`. It is followed by a lot of lines of warning that look like this `Target .... is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:53 and /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
$>sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                      
Hit:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                    
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                   
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                
Hit:6 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease                                                    
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                       
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu focal InRelease                                     
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                        
Ign:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionioc-pgdg InRelease                                                  
Hit:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg InRelease                                                   
Err:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionioc-pgdg Release                                                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.85.69 80]
Hit:13 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease                          
Hit:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                               
Hit:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease   
Hit:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Ign:18 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/5.x/apt stable InRelease
Hit:19 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/5.x/apt stable Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionioc-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the existing repository first, you had the one from Bionic, that's what causing the problem to begin with. Assuming it is resided on `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

Now add the correct repository for your system.

```
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql-12-postgis-2.5
```

Comment: You are awesome! I deleted in my /etc/apt/sources,list files all references to postgresql and added the one you gave me. It works like magic!

Comment: good to know. I always thought ubuntu does nice, with postgres/upgrades/etc. Until I lingered on ps11 for too long, and now `postgresql-11-postgis-2.5` was no longer available. after switching sources, I could finally `pg_upgradecluster`

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Lido also helped me to install Postgis on Ubuntu 18 (with PostgreSQL 10) but I had to install the packages libjson-c4 and libgcc-s1 from Debian repositories

Comment: This is rather a comment, not an answer to the question (there were unmet dependencies which you did not address). So if you can't comment, wait until you have enough reputation to to so.